# Sequence Number for Id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to configure my Mongo DB to create sequence number for an Id column. Ex. It has to start from 1001 and increase by 1 automatically when I insert next row. I have my schema definitions as part of Node.JS how to add this configuration in Node schema?

Comment: See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: +1 good solution  for db side javascript function. hadn't seen that before.

Comment: @sambomartin that JS is not designed to run sever side or be evaled, it is there for demonstration purposes for what you should code in your application.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't support this out of the box.  The way I've implemented this (albeit in C#) is to create a "Sequence" collection with a key and a next number.  You can atomically increment and return the next number then use this as the id in your collection.

This is a C# function, using the findandmodify mongodb command to fetch and update a sequence number for a given "key".

```
    public long GetNextSequenceNumber(string name, string key)
    {
        var update = new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("$inc", new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("SequenceNumber", 1))));
        var query = new BsonDocument("_id", key);

        var command = new CommandDocument { 
            { "findandmodify" , name },
            { "query", query},
            { "update" , update},
            { "new" , true},
        };

        var res = Db.RunCommand(command);

        if (res.Response["value"] != BsonNull.Value)
        {
            var o = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Sequence>(res.Response["value"].ToBsonDocument());
            return o.SequenceNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            var o = new Sequence() { Id = key, SequenceNumber = 0 };
            Db.GetCollection(name).Insert<Sequence>(o);
            return o.SequenceNumber;
        }
    }
```

and the Sequence model:

```
    public class Sequence
    {            
        public string Id { get; set; }        
        public long SequenceNumber { get; set; }       
    }
```

The sequence documents look like:

```
{
    _id : 'mykey',
    SequenceNumber : NumberLong(1234)
}
```

If you need converting it to javascript please ask.

Hope that helps.